# Inflating a view throws Resources$NotFoundException on physical device

Tags: java, android

The exact error:

```
07-16 18:34:41.729: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28347):     android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001
07-16 18:34:41.729: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28347):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
07-16 18:34:41.729: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28347):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1869)
07-16 18:34:41.729: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28347):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
07-16 18:34:41.729: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28347):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
...
```

The call:

```
LayoutInflater a = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
mainLayout.removeAllViews();                
mainLayout.addView(a.inflate(R.layout.input, null));
```

Bottom line throws the error.

The resource ID in the error is `R.layout.input`, which I'm trying to insert into another LayoutView `mainLayout`.

What's strange is that it only happens when I debug on my phone, when I run it in an emulator it works perfectly and adds the LayoutView as I want, yet if I try to debug on my phone it comes up with this error.

Comment: Did you manage to make it working? I having exactly same thing. Funny though on my Samsung device is absolutely OK.

Comment: My problem seemed to have been a version mismatch between designer and phone. I put my "solution" below, sorry I can't be of much more help.

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning the project with Project>Clean in Eclipse. This seems to clear up most of these inexplicable issues for me.

Comment: Done that a few times, nothing.

Comment: Are the device and emulator running the same Android version?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by remaking the LayoutView I was trying to add to the main view.

I think it was caused by me designing it using the 2.3.3 designer where as the phone was 2.2 (along with the application's target)

The strange this is that the 2.2 emulator worked using it, so I'm not entirely sure why it worked.